# Python flask sending image and GPS data to server

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to send both an image from the client side as well as GPS coordinates data to the server side. But currently I am only able to send either one of the data only it is not possible to send both at the same time. I tried sending my GPS coordinates data via JSON but it keeps on giving me none.

Here is the client-side code. main.py

```
import requests
import json
import cv2
import os
import random
import time

addr = 'http://localhost:5000'
test_url = addr + '/api/test'

while True:

   alt = random.randint(0, 99)
   x_cord = random.randint(0, 99)
   y_cord = random.randint(0, 99)
   z_cord = random.randint(0, 99)

   geotag = "A{}XX{}YY{}ZZ{}"
   geotag = geotag.format(alt, x_cord, y_cord, z_cord)

   geotag_j = json.dumps(geotag)

   print(geotag_j)
   print(type(geotag_j))
   # content_type = 'image/jpeg'
   # headers = {'content-type': content_type}

   IMAGE_FOLDER = './imagefolder'

   filename = random.choice(os.listdir(IMAGE_FOLDER))
   path = '%s/%s' % (IMAGE_FOLDER, filename)

   img = cv2.imread(path)


   # encode image as jpeg
   _, img_encoded = cv2.imencode('.jpg', img)
   # print(img_encoded)
   test=img_encoded.tostring()
   data2 = dict()
   data2['a'] = geotag
   print(data2)
   print(type(data2))
   y = json.dumps(data2)
   # send http request with image and receive response
   response= requests.post(test_url, data=test,json=y)

   # decode response
   print(json.loads(response.text))
   time.sleep(10)
```

Here is the server side

```
from flask import Flask, request, Response
import jsonpickle
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os
# Initialize the Flask application
app = Flask(__name__)
directory = r'C:\Users\AIG user\PycharmProjects\flaskProject\Image_sending\file_save'

#route http posts to this method
@app.route('/api/test', methods=['POST'])
def test():
    r = request
    # convert string of image data to uint8
    nparr = np.fromstring(r.data, np.uint8)
    # decode image
    img = cv2.imdecode(nparr, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

    # do some fancy processing here....
    os.chdir(directory)
    filename = 'savedImage.jpg'
    cv2.imwrite(filename, img)

    content = request.get_json()
    print("data is " + format(content))
    # build a response dict to send back to client
    response = {'message': 'image received. size={}x{}'.format(img.shape[1], img.shape[0])
                }
    # encode response using jsonpickle
    response_pickled = jsonpickle.encode(response)

    return Response(response=response_pickled, status=200, mimetype="application/json")


# start flask app
app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5000)
```

When i run request.get_json() it gives me none. How do I send both image and the GPS data?

I have tried following this method:
https://jdhao.github.io/2020/04/12/build_webapi_with_flask_s2/
But it wont't work

Comment: you can use `json` or `data` in the post request, not both.

Answer (score 0):

as @monkut said in comment, it is impossible to use different [types of data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types) in one request.

Possible solutions are:

1. [Encode image to base64 string](https://elmah.io/tools/base64-image-encoder/) and send as a JSON data:

```json
{
  "some_data1": "",
  "some_data2": "",
  "image": "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"
}
```

2. Use [`multipart/form-data`](https://www.appcoda.com/restful-api-tutorial-how-to-upload-files-to-server/) to be able mix text and binary data
3. Separate JSON and binary data into two different requests